# How to create a factory the value of which is set at runtime and can be retrieved at runtime in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory

I have to set the value of my service which provides csrf token at runtime. How do I go about this? Here is my attempt, but I see that the header `X-XSRF-TOKEN` is an object in the header when login happens. I think that the value of csrf_service is not retrieved in Authentication factory.

```
app.factory('csrfService', function(){
    this.csrf_token = null;
    return {
        setToken: function(value){
            this.csrf_token = value;
        },
        getToken: function(){
            return this.csrf_token;
        }
    };
});
```

And I inject it

```
app.run(function(csrfService){
    $http.get("api/auth/csrf_token").then(function(response) {          
        csrfService.setToken(response);         
    });
});
```

And I retrieve it

```
app.factory('Authentication', function(csrfService){
    return {
        login: function(){
            $http.post("api/auth/login", {
                userName: userName,
                password: password
            }, {headers:{'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfService.getToken()}})
            .then(function(result) {}
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: don't inject as string in `run`... isn't it throwing an error?

Comment: Sorry that was typo on the post, not in my code.

Comment: I created the following plunker which works http://plnkr.co/edit/8hPZ72GXcoh7TWEu1BZ9?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your setToken value response to response.data

```
app.run(function(csrfService){
    $http.get("api/auth/csrf_token").then(function(response) {          
        csrfService.setToken(response.data);         
    });
});
```

**EDIT :**

$http calls are async their callbacks can run any order. You may need to resolve your async data before the page load.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx
http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/show-route-only-after-all-promises-are-resolved

Comment: Hey, in my setToken function, I did console.log(this.csrf_token) once the value was set, and it was all fine(the token was logged). But after that when the getToken was called, it was empty. I suppose it's because when the csrfService is passed to factory, this.csrf_token is initialized to null. But how to avoid that?

Comment: Factories ,services all are singleton. They keep their state until you refresh or F5 page. Means that you reload page somewhere. If you need to keep that data you can use cookie or localstorage.

Comment: Another possibility your api/auth/csrf_token callback block run after you called login. If thats the problem you need to resolve your token before the page loaded. http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8hPZ72GXcoh7TWEu1BZ9?p=preview). The code works as I wanted. The relevant part of code is here.

script.js

```
angular.module('httpExample', [])
  .controller('FetchController', function($scope, Authentication){
    $scope.click = function(){
      Authentication.login();
    };
  })

  .factory('csrfService', function(){
    this.csrf_token = null;
    return {
        setToken: function(value){
            this.csrf_token = value;
            console.log('token is set as: '+this.csrf_token);
        },
        getToken: function(){
          console.log('token is retrieved as: '+this.csrf_token);
          return this.csrf_token;
        }
    };
  })

  .run(function(csrfService, $http){
    $http.get("hello.html").then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      csrfService.setToken(response.data);
    });
  })

  .factory('Authentication', function(csrfService, $http){
    return {
        login: function(){
            $http.post("api/auth/login", {
                userName: "userName",
                password: "password"
            }, {headers:{'X-XSRF-TOKEN': csrfService.getToken()}})
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // this callback will be called asynchronously
              // when the response is available
            })
        }
    };
  })

;
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="httpExample">
  <div ng-controller="FetchController">
    <div ng-click="click()">Click me</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

hello.html

```
Hello,Superman
```